# A question on relation between invariant subspace and eigen space of a linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, invariant-subspace

Suppose that $T:V\to V$ is a linear transformation and $V$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$. $W$ is a non-zero subspace of $V$ such that $T(W)\subset W$, that is $W$ is T-invariant. Does it mean that $T$ has a non-zero eigen vector in $W$?

I am not at all sure about where the answer is in positive. I also cannot find any counter. If I take for example $W=V$, then the hypothesis always hold but there exists non-zero eigen vector always due to the field being $\mathbb{C}$. But, I don't know what to do in case of arbitrary invariant subspace.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Can't you just think of the restriction of $T$ to $W$ and apply the argument you know for the case in which $W$ is everything?

Comment: oh right thank you very much, it was so dumb of me !!!

Comment: You're welcome. Mathematicians often think they're dumb after the fact. Not so. Either delete the question or post your own answer.